# Php File upload, rename file, and then return new filename on 'successful upload' page?

Tags: php, mysql, image, session, upload

I'm trying to return the name of a file uploaded using PHP after changing image files name upon uploading it.

I thought I could create a $_session['image_name'] and then call that session up on the subsequent "successful upload" page. I can't seem to get it correct. I need the name so that I can store it in the mysql database. Here's the part of my upload code that does the renaming and my attempt at creating a session:

/

```
/ make a unique filename for the uploaded file and check it is 
// not taken... if it is keep trying until we find a vacant one
$now = time();
while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']))
{
    $now++;
$_SESSION['image_name'] = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name'];
}
```

On my successfulUpload php page I was returning:

```
<p>Congratulations! Your file <? echo $_Session['image_name']; ?> upload was successful</p>
```

I have `session_start();` at the very top of both the uploadProcessing code and the Successful uploads page.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, session_start() on both files.

Answer (score 0):

I see now, on your success page, $_SESSION should be capitalized.

Comment: Thanks Codler...that was it :P